# Retain formatting of input string on parsing it to double

Tags: java

I have a scenario in providing values to a table from a csv file.

There, some of the columns have double values.

The catch is the double values can be of any double format i.e
either 81 or 81.0 or 8.1E1.

I just want to retain the double formatting after parsing the string to double.

example 
if string is 81.0 then format pattern should be ##.# and the double parsed should be 81.0 and not 81 or 81.00
if string is 12.12 then format pattern should be ##.## same as above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to retain the format, retain the original String.  You could have locale specific formats in a general case e.g. `1.234,00`

Answer (score 1):

You need your own value holder class like this:

```
public class Value<Raw> {
  private final Format format;
  private Raw value;
  private String display;

  public Value(String display, Format format) {
    this.format = format;
    this.display = display;
    value = format.parseObject(display);
  }

  public String getDisplay() {
    return display;
  }

  public Raw getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Raw value) {
    this.value = value;
    display = format.format(value);
  }

  public void setDisplay(String display) {
    this.display = display;
    value = format.parseObject(display);
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return value == null ? 0 : value.hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || Value.class != other.getCLass()) {
      return false;
    }
    Object otherValue = ((Value)other).value;
    return value == null ? otherRaw == null : value.equals(otherValue);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return display;
  }
}
```

The last is to determine the format. This is a little bit tricky depending on the locale and file format. For DecimalFormat you may replace all digits by # and reduce leading # to one. For languages like german you have the replace the decimal point and grouping separator before parsing the format.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) covers your use cases.

Additionally, `81.0 == 81` and `81.00 == 81.0` and `81 == 81.00` would all return true, meaning that if you parsed `81.00`, it would be stored in a Java double as `81`, there is no changing that.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep the pattern for later use, you may want to look into a regex to convert an instance of a pattern to the original pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to convert `double` to `string`, there is no chance to preserve format value of each `double` value.

Because `double` value is stored in binary.

The idea of trailing decimal zeros, as in 106.4000, is meaningless in a `double` value.